# Condición IF no valida variables

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito ayuda con `PHP`. Tengo que validar e ingresar datos de inscripción a un curso:

```
$usuario_id = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id_usuario, id_curso FROM inscripciones WHERE id_usuario='$user_id' and id_curso <>'$id_curso'");
         $id_usuario = 0;
         $curso_id = 0;
          if($usuario_id)
          {
              while ($registro_usuario = mysqli_fetch_array($usuario_id))
                { 
                  $id_usuario = $registro_usuario['id_usuario']; 
                  $curso_id = $registro_usuario['id_curso']; 
                }
          }
```

En esta parte del código, capturo el id del usuario, el id del curso y los guardo en las variables `$id_usuario` y `$curso_id` respectivamente:

```
if (($id_usuario==$user_id) && ($curso_id==$id_curso)){
          scriptAlertGo('El usuario ya esta inscrito en este curso','#');
           }else{
                $sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `capacitaciones`.`inscripciones` 
                  (`id_usuario`, `id_curso`, `estamento`, `email`, `fecha_jornada_curso`, `fecha_inscripcion`, `tipo_jornada`, `mensaje`, `aprobado`, `asistencia`) VALUES 
                  ('$user_id', '$id_curso','$estamento', '$mail', '$fechas_curso', NOW(), '$tipo_jornada', '$mensaje', 'pendiente', 'pendiente')");

                 $resta_vacantes = ("UPDATE `capacitaciones`.`cursos` set `vacantes` = `vacantes` - 1 where `cursos`.`id_curso` = '$id_curso'");
                 mysqli_query($con, $resta_vacantes);

                 scriptAlertGo('El usuario quedo registrado en este curso','index.php');
```

En esta otra parte del código, hago el `if` para validar si `$id_usuario` es igual a la variable `$user_id`, y lo mismo con `$curso_id` (si es igual a `$id_curso`). Si cumplen esta condición, el sistema entrega una alerta de "El usuario ya está inscrito en este curso", y si no la cumplen, registra los datos en la tabla de inscripciones.

El problema está en que, ahora como está, registra de todas formas los datos a la tabla de inscripciones, independiente de si se cumple la condición `if` o no.

¿Dónde puede estar el problema? ¿Tengo mal escrita la condición `if`?

Comment: verificaste que el dato de $user_id y $id_usuario sean los mismos? porque si dices que te está haciendo las inscripciones alguna de tus dos condiciones no se está cumpliendo

Comment: si, lo verifique con un echo $user_id... y son los mismos

Answer (score 3):

Aca hay un tema de logica.

Que pasa si el usuario se inscribio ya en dos cursos, digamos el curso 1 y 2, y luego quiere volver a inscribirse en el 1?

Pues, lo va a inscribir. Y esto porque pasa?

Por lo siguiente:

```
SELECT id_usuario, id_curso FROM inscripciones WHERE id_usuario='$user_id' and id_curso <>'$id_curso'
```

Aca le estas pidiendo que traiga todos los cursos para este usuario distintos al curso en el cual se quiere anotar. Y si.. obviamente el curso 1 no esta.

Entonces, cuando armas tus nuevas variables, el usuario es el mismo, pero el curso que trajiste, no. Entonces lo inscribe.

Yo creo que querias hacer lo contrario. fijarte primero si el usuario estaba en el curso haciendo:

```
SELECT count(*) total FROM inscripciones WHERE id_usuario='$user_id' and id_curso ='$id_curso'
```

Y con este query, verificar si esa cuenta da 0 o mas. si da 0, entonces no tiene este curso, si da mas, ya lo tiene y no tiene que inscribirse.

Comment: Yo le pondría un *alias* a la columna resultante, para así poder recuperar el dato con mayor claridad: `SELECT count(*) total FROM inscripciones WHERE  ...`  y luego recuperarla con algo como: `$res['total'];` usando preferentemente `fetch_assoc`

Comment: Totalmente valido @A.Cedano, ahora hago el cambio en el query. No escribi la parte de php, porque habria que cambiar todo el código, y vos sabes mucho mas que yo de eso ;)

Comment: cualquier ayuda es bienvenida chicos :)